# How to read all inbox messages of android phone through ionic 1 or 2

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I tried SMS.listSMS in v1 and 
window.SMS in v2 [I followed this link v2](http://pointdeveloper.com/read-sms-list-with-ionic-2/)

Both didnt worked out

Comment: I tried cardova-plugin-sms in v1 please help me with clear explanation.